# Removing duplicate sequence from multiple movie files

Tags: video, video-editing

I like to download & binge watch TV shows, however a lot of time is spent skipping the same intro/outro sequence - is there any sort of program that I can run to scan multiple movie files (MP4/mkv h.264) and remove duplicate sequences of between 30-180 seconds? I wouldn't mind if it takes a while to run as long as it can remove them and/or make a copy of the movie files without the duplicate sequences

FLOSS would be preferred, as would windows/linux, but I would be interested to in all options

P.S. - yes I know netflix/etc. has a button that's literally "skip intro", but I want an even more automated solution, as often I have my hands busy with popcorn or I am bundled up nicely and don't want to move / bring up the menu even if it's only a 2 second interruption